# how to connect blue yeti mic to galaxy nexus

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, audio, 4.2-jelly-bean, usb-peripherals

I'd like to use the blue yeti as audio input for recording video on the galaxy nexus. How can I achieve this? I know thus far that I need a USB otg cable, but when I plugged it in it didn't seem to be recognized. I'm running android jelly bean 4.2 and am using stock camera app for video recording.

Answer (score 1):

I think you cannot do it yet because the drivers do not support it.

You can record audio on its own, though. USB Audio Recorder Pro from the Google Play store may work for this purpose. If you search for it, the description contains a link that will allow you to download a demo version for testing.

It definitely works with the Blue Yeti on Nexus 7 as reported by the developer, and a number of other devices.

Note that it has to be USB Audio Recorder Pro by extream software development (to which I am not affiliated), and not USB Audio Recorder which is a different product.

Whereas this is not a full answer to your question, I hope it helps.

Comment: You could then re-sync this to the video, using any good video editor, including the many free ones.